# Generic Linked List in java

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

I am learning generics and want to create a generic linked list.

But i am getting following compile time error.

> ```
> Type mismatch: cannot convert from LinkedList<E>.Node<E> to
>  LinkedList<E>.Node<E>
> ```

```
public class LinkedList<E> {
    private Node<E> head = null;

    private class Node<E> {
        E value;
        Node<E> next;

        // Node constructor links the node as a new head
        Node(E value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = head;//Getting error here
            head = this;//Getting error here
        }
    }

    public void add(E e) {
        new Node<E>(e);
    }

    public void dump() {
        for (Node<E> n = head; n != null; n = n.next)
            System.out.print(n.value + " ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.add("world");
        list.add("Hello");
        list.dump();
    }
}
```

Please let me know why i am getting this error ??

Comment: You do not need to set `Node` generic. Since it is an inner class, it will be generic due to the generic nature of the surrounding class.

Comment: Setting the inner class generic type E is not working since `The type parameter E is hiding type E` (compiler warning on line 4)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `E` here  `private class Node<E> {`  hides the `E` here :`public class LinkedList<E> {`

The `Node` class doesn't need to be generics.
It contains a generics field `value` that depends on the `E` generics from `LinkedList`. It is enough.

```
public class LinkedList<E> {
    private Node head = null;

    private class Node {
        E value;
        Node next;

        // Node constructor links the node as a new head
        Node(E value) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = head;//Getting error here
            head = this;//Getting error here
        }
    }

    public void add(E e) {
        new Node(e);
    }

    public void dump() {
        for (Node n = head; n != null; n = n.next)
            System.out.print(n.value + " ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.add("world");
        list.add("Hello");
        list.dump();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

> could you please tell me what compiler wants to say when it throw
>   error message

When you write :

```
 this.next = head;
```

you have to be aware that these two variables don't rely on the same type.

- `next` is a field declared in `Node<E>` class in this way :  `Node<E> next`
- `head` is a field declared in `LinkedList<E>` class in this way :  `Node<E> head`

But the `E` type declared in the `Node<E>` class is not considered by the compiler as being the same `E` type declared in the  `LinkedList<E>` class **because these are two distinct type declarations**.

So here :

```
this.next = head;
```

the compiler cannot assign from `LinkedList<E>.Node<E>` to `LinkedList<E>.Node<E>` because the `Node<E> next` field from the `Node<E>`class and the `Node<E> head` field  from the `LinkedList<E>`class don't declare the 
same type (and are not convertible either).

Comment: could you please tell me what compiler wants to say when it throw error message